# How to import obj file with multiple textures?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, modeling

I have downloaded a .obj file from "opengameart" and that looks awesome. But I am not being able to set it up in the unity. That contains a textures folder where there are more than 30 images. And I drag and drop that all in the unity. But that is not working. I converted that to .fbx . I even tried embed media but a log file is being generated saying .mtl file fail
[image]

https://opengameart.org/content/bowling-alley-model
This is the link to the bowling alley asset. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OBJ` file that you are using doesn't contain the `MTL` file which contains the texture information for `OBJ` file.

Opening bowling alley `obj` file in blender, adding some texture and exporting it again to `obj` format creates a `MTL` file with `OBJ` file.

Importing the `OBJ` file with `MTL` file resulted in `obj` to have material texture in unity. See unity screenshot for `obj` with `mtl` file

[image]

Comment: Yes, you can use maya, 3ds, blender and many more tools available free as well as paid.

Comment: When I open obj in blender only cube appears and nothing else. Is that a problem with my blender

Comment: That is the default scene in blender. You can delete the cube and then import the Bowling Alley obj file to work on it. Here is a random tutorial for adding texture in blender http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-add-a-texture-in-Blender/

Comment: Thanks Stackoverflow is heaven

Comment: It was a pleasure helping you :)